# Chrome scroll is locked

Tags: macos, google-chrome, scrolling

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac OS 10.9
When I opened a new webpage, I can't scroll it down. 
Only after I moved to another tab and then come back, the scrolling works.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It also can happen on Ubuntu 13.10. The problem seems intermittent, and I know someone else on a Mac was having this problem. Fortunately [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) doesn't have this problem, so that is one good solution. You could dig up an older Chrome version, but that would have security vulnerabilities.